# Ellipses not shown on canvas by adding them as children but do when added in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, ellipse

As the title states , I have a wiimote in my application which provides the pixel coordinates at which the Ellipses need to be shown. Problem is however that when I add them with `Canvas.Children.Add()`, they do not appear on the canvas.

If however I add the ellipses in the canvas with XAML and then modify their coordinates each time a new x,y coordinate is provided by the remote then the ellipses appear on the canvas and seem to be changing the positions.

```
   if (remote == service.wiimote1_info)
        {
            Action action = () =>
            {
                WM1Status_Lbl.Content = remote.Astatus.ToString();
                WM1_Accel_X.Content = remote.Accelerometer[0].ToString();
                WM1_Accel_Y.Content = remote.Accelerometer[1].ToString();
                WM1_Accel_Z.Content = remote.Accelerometer[2].ToString();
                WM1_IR1.Content = String.Concat(" X = ", remote.IRState[0, 0]/10, "; Y = ", remote.IRState[0, 1]/10, "; Size = ", remote.IRState[0, 2]);
                WM1_IR2.Content = String.Concat(" X = ", remote.IRState[1, 0]/10, "; Y = ", remote.IRState[1, 1]/10, "; Size = ", remote.IRState[1, 2]);
                WM1_IR3.Content = String.Concat(" X = ", remote.IRState[2, 0]/10, "; Y = ", remote.IRState[2, 1]/10, "; Size = ", remote.IRState[2, 2]);
                WM1_IR4.Content = String.Concat(" X = ", remote.IRState[3, 0]/10, "; Y = ", remote.IRState[3, 1]/10, "; Size = ", remote.IRState[3, 2]);
                wm1_progressbar.Value = remote.battery;
                //IRImage.Children.Clear();
                Canvas.SetLeft(IRSensor1, remote.IRState[0, 0] ) ; Canvas.SetBottom(IRSensor1, remote.IRState[0, 1]);
                Canvas.SetLeft(IRSensor2, remote.IRState[1, 0]); Canvas.SetBottom(IRSensor2, remote.IRState[1, 1]);
                Canvas.SetLeft(IRSensor3, remote.IRState[2, 0] ); Canvas.SetBottom(IRSensor3, remote.IRState[2, 1] );
                Canvas.SetLeft(IRSensor4, remote.IRState[3, 0]); Canvas.SetBottom(IRSensor4, remote.IRState[3, 1]);

                //At first I tryed to add the sensors with my DrawSensor() method , but it did not work . So then I have decided to modify already existing sensors instead of continuousely creating new ones .   

                DrawSensor(System.Drawing.Color.Blue, remote.IRState[0, 0]/10, remote.IRState[0,1]/10, (int)remote.IRState[0, 2]+1);
                DrawSensor(System.Drawing.Color.Red, remote.IRState[1, 0]/10, remote.IRState[1, 1]/10, (int)remote.IRState[1, 2]+1);
                DrawSensor(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, remote.IRState[2, 0]/10, remote.IRState[2, 1]/10, (int)remote.IRState[2, 2]+1);
                DrawSensor(System.Drawing.Color.Green, remote.IRState[3, 0]/10, remote.IRState[3, 1]/10, (int)remote.IRState[3, 2]+1);

            };
            Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
            updated = true;
        }



  public void DrawSensor(System.Drawing.Color color , double x , double y , int Size )
    {
        Ellipse sensor = new Ellipse();
        sensor.Width = Size + 1;
        sensor.Height = Size + 1;
        sensor.Opacity = 100;
        Canvas.SetTop(sensor , x);
        Canvas.SetBottom(sensor , y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(sensor, y);
        IRImage.Children.Add(sensor);
        Console.WriteLine("Point drawn");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that you forget to add the Fill property for the Ellipse sensor in the DrawSensorMethod

```
sensor.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

But more important, I encourage you instead of creating new ellipses each time, just create 4 or the amount you need and use TranslateTransform to move them, it uses the GPU instead the CPU and the effect is smooth

Comment: Thank's alot for your suggestion. The missing fill property was why my Ellipses were not showing . Also the suggestion you made really helped . The animation is alot more smoother now .

Comment: Apparently I jumped too fast to conclusion . After I used the TranslateTransform the first run of the program worked very smoothly... however , one I added a second controller it started running the same as before . I disconected the second remote but the Ellipses behave the same .

Comment: But you are instancing Ellipses just once?

Comment: Yes , only once , and then I modify the position with a ´Ellipse.RenderTransform = TranslateTransform ´ line.

Comment: (Ellipse.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X += 10.0 for instance?

Comment: It is the same ... It seems to have it's moments when it is running smoothly  .Also the only ellipse that is show on the canvas is the last one that was transfomed. All the other ones do not show.

Comment: might be some exception?, and trying in release mode? withou debugging?